# Postr Wall To Fans Page Using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am trying to post wall through my application with Facebook Graph API to user's fan page. Please give me ideas how can I past wall to the fan page using Graph API and without using the access token of fans page .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you will definitely need an access token

Answer (score 1):

Posting as Admin is easy but posting as Page requires more work from your side. To post as Page we need the following permissions:

- publish_stream
- manage_pages

We need the manage_pages permission to get the page access token so we can post on its behalf. And this is how we do it:

```
$page_id = "XXXXXXXXX";
$page_access_token = "";
$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
    if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
        $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
        break;
    }
}
$args = array(
    'access_token'  => $page_access_token,
    'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

I'd recommend you to read [Graph API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

And the above example is from: [How To: Post On Facebook Page As Page Not As Admin User Using PHP-SDK](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you idea to read [API manual](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

- You need user's access token
- You need user's publish stream permissions
- You'll post it to https://graph.facebook.com/FAN_PAGE_ID/feed with post fields

  - access_token
  - message